# Nhibernate SQL Server 2016 dialect

Tags: c#, sql-server, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm looking to use NHibernate with SQL Server 2016.

The latest dialect is for SQL Server 2012 and would therefore allow all SQL Server 2012 functionality within SQL Server 2016. I want to know if the new SQL Server 2016 functionality is in any way available via NHibernate.

I'm mainly interested in the following functionality:

- In-Memory Tables
- Transparent Data Encryption
- Row Level Security

Is this functionality available out of the box in the latest (Feb 2017) version of NHibernate and if not are there any ready made extensions that enable the use of this functionality ?

Comment: Note that so long as you are managing the database schema independently, NHibernate should be compatible with each of these features.  TDE and RLS are entirely transparent to the application.  And In-Memory Tables will mostly work, but you'll probably want to use native compiled stored procedures to access objects, and you'll need to have retry logic for optimistic concurrency commit conflicts.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft do you have links to any code showcasing using memory tables with NH ?

Comment: No.  I never use NHibernate.  But normal SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE, and DELTETE work the same with In-Memory tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These features are highly SQL-Server dependent, and are to be enabled on server side. This a DBA task, not an ORM task (Object Relational Mapping tool -
 NHibernate is an ORM, Entity Framework too).

If your DBA supports them, just ask him to enable them. There is nothing to be done on NHibernate side.

- [In-Memory Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/in-memory-oltp-in-memory-optimization):
  You have to flag tables to be handled with in-memory OLTP as memory-optimized when creating them.
  If you use NHibernate hbm2ddl tool to create your tables, you then need to change your process for creating them yourself. hbm2ddl is far too database agnostic for handling those kind of specific options.
- [Transparent Data Encryption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/transparent-data-encryption-tde):
  This is fully SQL Server concern. That encrypts the database files. This is completely transparent for client software like NHibernate. It has no impact on them. That is a bit nonsense to ask support in clients for a feature which is a server only feature, to which clients are never exposed.
- [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security):
  Again, fully handled server side. Again, a bit nonsense to ask support in clients for a feature which is a server side feature. Have you documented yourself a bit on those technologies before asking? Read more on Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security).

  > The access restriction logic is located in the database tier rather than away from the data in another application tier.

Defining the filters/access rules in database is your job (or your dba job). This has never been the job of an ORM.

It is wholly up to you (or your dba) to enable them, and they will just work, whatever the application, be it NHibernate or something else.

Answer (score 0):

These features are not available. You will need to create tickets in JIRA (https://nhibernate.jira.com) and maybe discuss them with the developers of NHibernate (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/nhibernate-development).

Comment: Do you know if they are looking at any of those or are they slowly giving up on the product?

Comment: Well, it's a community work, you are free to contribute. I guess it depends on each of the developer's priorities, but the project has been quite stale for some time.

Comment: Have asked NH and they have replied that none of those features are NH specific.

Comment: Quite stale? The [contrib graph](https://github.com/nhibernate/nhibernate-core/graphs/contributors) is not really flat. @user3213045, being unrelated with NHibernate just means NHibernate has nothing to do with them. Enable them, and they should just work. Otherwise please provide concrete cases where you do not get the expected behavior.

Comment: @Ricardo Peres, would you have a look at my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47536695/cannot-use-nhibernate-code-mapping-for-a-private-field.  It is similar to the question, which you answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nhusers/wiH1DPGOhgU.  Thanks.